# Как получить результат SELECT из EXECUTE

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$prepare = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ?");
$prepare -> execute(["value"]);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить результат **SELECT** в данном случае, ведь **EXECUTE** выдаёт тип **BOOL**. Через **QUERY** напрямую всё получается, но как это сделать через **PREPARE**?

Comment: Смотрите методы fetch. fetchAll, fetchColumn они вызываются после execute для получения собственно данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться одной из fetch-функций, например, `fetchAll()`

```
$prepare = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ?");
$prepare -> execute(["value"]);

$results = $prepare->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $result)
  echo $result['name']."<br />";
```

Comment: так просто? Спасибо, ответ оказывается лежал на поверхности! Я пробовал $r = $prepare -> execute(["value"]) -> fetchAll(); - не пошло, и это сбило с толку